# adding two numeric strings - MIPS ASSEMBLY

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips, addition

I am working on a MIPS Assembly program. I am new at this, and am having some trouble.

How do you convert digits in a .asciiz string to there numeric counter parts.

EX:
"1" -> 49

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, it should probably be tagged 'homework'.

Comment: I have no idea about MIPS assembly, but generally you should use a debugger to single step your code and identify where it goes wrong.
Also, I am unsure why 1+2=5 ;)

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a debugger?
and thank you for pointing that error it was supposed to be 2 + 3, but i was thinking string 1 and string 2

Comment: The strings aren't converted in numerical values, are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use a simulator like http://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/:

```
.data
input:    .asciiz "1234"

.text
main:   
    la $t0, input         # load address of input
loop:
    lb $a0, ($t0)         # load one byte
    beq $a0, $0, exit     # exit if null-byte
    li $v0, 1             # print integer system call
    syscall             
    addi $t0, $t0, 1      # increment address
    j loop

exit:   
    jr $ra
```

Output:
49505152

Comment: How would you go about doing this except starting from the end of the string? So the result would look like 52515049